# How to join an BITMAIN Antminer to a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Active Directory

Tags: dns, active-directory, angstrom-linux

### Let's start with "*WHY?*":#nerdsLoveToStartWithWhy

I'm developing a customized software to manage a crypto-mining farm where we need to communicate with miners (BITMAIN Antminer) by their **hostname** instead of IP (just for ease of use).

> I know! But I don't want to scan IP ranges, then either SSH to them or use API to pull out the information such as the hostname

### My Solution:(please share if you have a better solution)

I've configured a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Active Directory & DNS with a domain name as `ts.facility.com` and I'm trying to join my Antminers to this domain.

**Scenario:**
The `SRV1` is my AC DC and visible to the miners. The miner with a hostname as `antMinerThree` which is running a `linux Angstrom V2013.12` are getting reply from the ACDC with its FQDN. the `ntpdate` package is installed as perquisite:

command: `#opkg install ntpdate`
[image]

### Problem:

The problem for now is that when to install required packages:

> samba
>   krb5-config
>   krb5-user
>   winbind
>   libpam-winbind
>   libnss-winbind

I got the following error: bmminer.list

[image]

Failed to open //var/lib/opkg/info/bmminer.list: No such file or directory.

and when I created manually an empty file `bmminer.list` in the path `/var/lib/opkg/info/` I still get this error message, unless it no longer complains about missing bmminer.list:

[image]

### Question

Does any body know, how to install required packages to joint this miner running Linux Angstrom V2013.12 to a Microsoft Windows Active Directory 2008 in order that I could ping my miners by hostname instead of by their IP addresses?

Comment: Why is there a `//` in the path: *//var/lib/opkg/info/bmminer.list*? Please check the relevant configuration file.